# Grails 2.4.3 considers FATAL log level as ERROR

Tags: log4j

I'm learning about log4j configuration in Grails. Below is my Config.groovy. The logger grails.app.controllers.logging.FatalController is configured to log fatal level only.

```java
log4j.main = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    fatal 'grails.app.controllers.logging.FatalController'

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    warn 'grails.app.services.logging.WarnService',
         'grails.app.controllers.logging.WarnController'
```

This is my FatalController.groovy:

```java
package logging

class FatalController {
        def index(){
                log.debug("This is not shown")
                log.warn("neither this")
                log.error("or that")
                log.fatal("but this does")

                render "logged"
        }
}
```

Now, when I execute this I expected it to log "but this does".  However it doesn't. When I changed Config.groovy line:

```java
fatal 'grails.app.controllers.logging.FatalController'
```

to this:

```java
all 'grails.app.controllers.logging.FatalController'
```

The output I get is this:

```java
2014-10-15 12:33:04,070 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG logging.FatalController  - This is not shown
2014-10-15 12:33:04,071 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] WARN  logging.FatalController  - neither this
| Error 2014-10-15 12:33:04,072 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR logging.FatalController  - or that
| Error 2014-10-15 12:33:04,072 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR logging.FatalController  - but this does
```

Notice that the message "but this does" is defined in FatalController.groovy to be logged as fatal

```java
log.fatal("but this does")
```

And what the log message say is that it is a ERROR level message log:

```java
| Error 2014-10-15 12:33:04,072 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR logging.FatalController  - but this does
```

So there are two problems: 1) FATAL log messages are not shown when the logger level is defined as FATAL and 2) when I code log.fatal("something"), the log shows it as an ERROR level message.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you resolved? I have the same issue :( Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a Grails bug (I'm using Grails 2.4.5).

I found a workaround: try to use log4j in "old way".

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

class FatalController {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass())

    def index() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Another way could be overriding fatal function in Bootstrap.groovy: https://kousenit.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/log-roflfun-with-groovy-metaprogramming/ .
But it doesn't work for me :(